# Confusion regarding FROM_UNIXTIME

Tags: mysql

I am running MYSQL 4.1 database that stores call center data for our offices that operate in Europe.

My MYSQL database sits on a Windows 2003 server that's has its time zone set to Central European Time, which automatically adjusts to day light savings.

I want to able to produce a report that shows the  log date and time in the correct time zone to our customers in Europe.

My database stores the log date / time of the call as a unix time stamp. So therefore the dates stored as UTC. I found MYSQL function that can easily adjust the log date time to a time zone of your choice.

It's called **CONVERT_TZ**. (More info:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz)

Example: `SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','UTC','CET');`

I tried to apply this to call that was logged on 01-06-2013 22:12

```
CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(o.logdatex), 'UTC','CET') 'CET_L_DATETIME'
```

(logdatex is the unxtimestamp for when the call was logged)

To my confusion the statement returned - 2013-06-02 00:12:56.

I wanted to see what was returned when I just selected `FROM_UNIXTIME(o.logdatex)`

It returned the correct time! 2013-06-01 22:12:56 (This call was logged from our Amsterdam office)

My question is, does the FROM_UNIXTIME function automatically adjust the time from UTC according to what the  time zone MYSQL server is set to? I cannot find any documentation that says it does.

Comment: 4.1? Why are you running software that's 10 years old

Comment: @Strawberry could be a typo, given he refers to the 5.1 manual...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption this is because when you do `FROM_UNIXTIME(o.logdatex)` you convert from UTC to timezone of your server.
And now you date is not in UTC timezone. So  in `CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(o.logdatex), 'UTC','CET')` you don't convert from 'UTC' but from timezone of your server so you get a strange result for you.
Try to select `FROM_UNIXTIME(o.logdatex)` as a separate field in your query and compare results.